# How to alternate jquery toggle slide actions on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show two elements on click, one after the other, whereby a user clicks a button the first element with a class(`.show-element-one`), is shown and when the user clicks the same button for the second time the second element is shown with class(`.show-element-two`) , am using the code below to show element one on click but I am stuck with showing the second element on the second click.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#display-elements').click(function() {
    jQuery('.show-element-one,.show-element-two').toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

I will appreciate any guides, thanks.

Comment: Please present a testable example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a counter variable calculate the modulus value for that to display the element of that two classes in circular manner. Something like the code below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 1;
  jQuery('#display-elements').click(function() {
    jQuery('.show-element-one, .show-element-two').hide();
    if (count % 2 !== 0) {
      jQuery('.show-element-one').toggle("slide");
    } else {
      jQuery('.show-element-two').toggle("slide");
    }
    count++;
  });
});
```

```css
.show-element-one,
.show-element-two {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="display-elements"> Click me </button>
<div class="show-element-one">
  show-element-one
</div>
<div class="show-element-two">show-element-two </div>
```

Comment: perfect, the solution i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing the definition for `.slide` CSS class. Try the below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#display-elements').click(function() {
    $('.show-element-one,.show-element-two').toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

```css
.slide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="show-element-one">show-element-one</div>
<div class="show-element-two slide">show-element-two</div>

<button id="display-elements">Toggle</button>
```